# Why Do Images Sometimes Pop-up and Other Times Not?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bug

### Chat Exchange

When images are uploaded to **The Heap™ – Consultancy ©®** they will be loaded via API to Imgur. The link then gets sent back to the room and inserted into the chat feed. Depending on its original size the image is displayed as a thumbnail. **Clicking on the Image will open the original sized image in a new window, a tabbed window or as a pop-up depending on your browswer settings.**

### DBA.SE

When images are uploaded to **Database Administrators** they will be loaded via API to Imgur. The link then gets sent back to the input field and is inserted into the question or answer. Depending on its original size the image is displayed as a thumbnail. **Clicking on the Image will open the original sized image in the same window.**

### Question(s)

Why do the images react differently depdning on whether chat.stackexchange.com is used or dba.stackexchange.com when adding images?

Is this a bug? Or is it a Feature?

If it is a bug/feature, could this be corrected to always produce the same action when clicking on images?

Comment: Likely a simple bug where the image tag doesn't get rendered with a target attribute. Most devs I know are okay with ctrl-clicks.

Comment: right-click, "open in new window".  Default action for almost *every* link.

Comment: @MaxVernon *Do you want to close 134 tabs?*

Comment: I have no objections with CTRL + Right-click, but it would be nice if it were consistent over all the sites. _Ok, DBA.SE and Chat would be sufficient._

Comment: @TomV - I have the entire internet open in tabs.

Comment: @jcolebrand you are right with your edit. Thanks.